# Unable to finalize capture in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

It seems like after the last update I've made to `org-mode` the capturing of notes does not work properly. Currently I have version 8.0.7 (20130930) from the `ELPA`. Hitting `C-c c` (i.e. `org-capture`) brings the list of capture templates and then I can choose one of them to open a buffer where I can actually entry the note. The problem is that once I'm done, hitting `C-c C-c` doesn't close the capturing buffer. The content is saved in the right place but I'm not returned to the place where I started the capturing. In the `*Messages*` buffer I get the following error: `org-capture-finalize: Symbol's value as variable is void: org-bookmark-names-plist`

I don't really know where to start debugging this problem. Any ideas?

I believe the following are all the related setting that I have:

```
;; Capture-org
(setq org-default-notes-file (concat org-directory "/notes.org"))
(define-key global-map "\C-cc" 'org-capture)

(setq org-capture-templates
      (quote (("t" "todo" entry (file (concat org-directory "/gtd.org"))
               "* TODO %?\n%U\n%a\n" :clock-in t :clock-resume t)
              ("n" "note" entry (file (concat org-directory "/gtd.org"))
               "* %? :NOTE:\n%U\n%a\n" :clock-in t :clock-resume t)
              ("j" "Journal" entry (file+datetree (concat org-directory "/diary.org"))
               "* %?\n%U\n" :clock-in t :clock-resume t)
              ("v" "Vocabulary" entry
               (file+headline (concat org-directory "/vocab.org")
                              "Vocabulary")
               "* %^{The word} :drill:\n:PROPERTIES:\n:Part-of-speech: %^{Part of speech|verb|noun|adj|adv}\n:END:\n %t\n %^{Extended word (may be empty)} \n** Answer \n%^{The definition}")
              )))
```

Comment: Do you have an `@` symbol in your `org-todo-keywords`, which is one method of triggering the notes?  Perhaps you have notes triggered with the `@` symbol in your `org-todo-keywords` *and* you are also trying to trigger it a second time in your `org-capture-templates`?

Comment: @lawlist: `C-h v org-todo-keywords` yields: `Its value is ((sequence "TODO" "DONE"))`; so it seems not to be the case.

Comment: See also this related post of mine: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/77368

Comment: Is your goal to enter the text of the `:NOTE:` in a completely separate buffer (different than the template)?  For example, if the template creates a drawer for `:NOTE:`, instead of just moving the cursor down to that drawer and typing the note, would you rather have a completely separate buffer to enter the text of your note?

Comment: @lawlist: My goal, and this is how it used to work, is to hit `C-c c`, type my captured text, then hit `C-c C-c` so the text will be filed in the right file and the capturing buffer will be closed. At the end of this sequence, I want to end in the same place where it started and have the captured text saved in the right place.

Comment: If you have your older version of `org-capture.el`, then you can `diff` it with the newer version and try to see what changes have been made that might affect the behavior you experience.  That would also facilitate filing an informative bug report.

Comment: @lawlist: This could have been a nice idea... However, all the following are the same: `org-plus-contrib-20130930/org-capture.el`, `org-plus-contrib-20130923/org-capture.el`, `org-20130930/org-capture.el` and `org-20130923/org-capture.el` which are the versions that I have.

Comment: With a current version of Emacs Trunk built today, your code works just fine -- i.e., no error message.  Therefore, there is probably something else in your configuration that is causing the error you experience, or, there may be a problem with your Emacs installation itself.

Comment: Also tested with Emacs Trunk (built today) and installation of org version 20130930 from ELPA -- no errors with the code provided in the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there was some conflict between an older version and the current one in the ELPA directory. Removing the older version solved the problem for me.

Comment: Glad to hear that your problem has been resolved.